# Compiling plplot with gfortran

Tags: plot, fortran, gfortran

Gfortran compilation fails with plplot graphics library.

FYI: Plplot is a graphics library with which one can plot directly from gfortran (among other languages).

I have installed the following packages (on Xubuntu 18.04)

```
sudo apt install gfortran libplplot15 libplplot-dev libplplotfortran0 plplot-driver-cairo plplot-driver-qt plplot-driver-wxwidgets plplot-driver-xwin plplot-doc
```

I updated the local database with the following command: `sudo updatedb`. When I ran the command `locate plplot` I get the following relevant lines (along with other lines)

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/plplot-fortran.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/plplot.pc
```

Then I tried to compile the fortran example code given [here](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php?demo=00&lbind=Fortran) (relevant part is given below)

```
program x00f
use plfortrandemolib

integer, parameter :: NSIZE = 101

real(kind=pl_test_flt), dimension(NSIZE) :: x, y

real(kind=pl_test_flt) :: xmin = 0._pl_test_flt, xmax = 1._pl_test_flt, ymin = 0._pl_test_flt, ymax = 100._pl_test_flt
! integer          :: i
integer :: plparseopts_rc

! Prepare data to be plotted.
x = arange(NSIZE) / real(NSIZE-1,pl_test_flt)
y = ymax * x**2

! Or alternatively, using a DO-loop
!do i = 1,NSIZE
!    x(i) = real( i - 1, pl_test_flt ) / real( NSIZE - 1, pl_test_flt )
!    y(i) = ymax * x(i)**2
!enddo

! Parse and process command line arguments
plparseopts_rc = plparseopts( PL_PARSE_FULL )
if(plparseopts_rc .ne. 0) stop "plparseopts error"

! Initialize plplot
call plinit

! Create a labelled box to hold the plot.
call plenv( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, 0, 0 )
call pllab( "x", "y=100 x#u2#d", "Simple PLplot demo of a 2D line plot" )

! Plot the data that was prepared above.
call plline( x, y )

! Close PLplot library
call plend

end program x00f
```

with the following command

```
gfortran x00f.f90 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran)
```

The output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran` is

```
-I/usr/include/plplot -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/modules/plplot -I/usr/include/plplot -lplplotfortran
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
/tmp/ccAQ0C7A.o: In function `MAIN__':
x00f.f90:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `__plfortrandemolib_MOD_arange_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do I need to install any other packages or is the compilation command is incomplete? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @VladimirF: Added the code and the output of $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran) in the question above. Since the code is not really my code, but is a standard example, I had put a link to it.

Comment: Does plfortrandemolib.mod exist on your system?  If yes, then you need to specify the path to the module on the command line.  If no, then you need to install the module in place that gfortran can find it.

Comment: @evets: It exists in the following path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/modules/plplot/plfortrandemolib.mod`

Comment: @evets: Tried using the following command: `gfortran x00f.f90 -L/usr/lib/ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran)`. Still no luck. I get the same error message.

Comment: @evets: Finally figured it out. The command to compile would be `gfortran x00f.f90 -lplfortrandemolib $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran)`. Every time I use a new module, do I have to specify each of the modules individually even if I am using the `pkg-config` command?

Comment: I think you oftn do not need the demo lib and then the original command will be enough. But you must sure to always link any library from which you use any symbols. Doo not that Fortran modules nd the libraries you link with `-l` are not the same and do not correspond to each other 1:1.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question for future SO users. 
The correct compilation command for the above code is

```
gfortran x00f.f90 -lplfortrandemolib $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplot-fortran)
```

Also check VladimirF's comment on the same.